# SQL Query for Chart JS

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the a table like this.

```
| id  | question_id | option_id |
---------------------------------
| 1   |         1   |         1 |
| 1   |         1   |         2 |
| 1   |         1   |         3 |
| 1   |         1   |         2 |
| 1   |         1   |         2 |
| 1   |         1   |         6 |
```

How would I query for the result as follows?

```
[
  {'1' => 1},
  {'2' => 3},
  {'3' => 1},
  {'4' => 0},
  {'5' => 0},
  {'6' => 1},
]
```

Currently what I have is by looping the query from 1 to 6. Is there a way for me to query the counts for all possible value of option_id without knowing about the possible values (1 to 6)?

```
Select sum(case when option_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as "1" FROM fcs_answer WHERE question_id = 4;
```

Comment: Not clear enough what you're trying to do, please edit, what is that result?

Comment: Why would you want query to give you data in format you are expecting?

Comment: @delboy1978uk the result would be something like the json shown

Comment: @SMA to be used in a bar chart

Comment: The re-formatting of the data will need to happen in PHP - it sounds like a very simple `foreach` loop - but you haven't shown us what PHP you have right now. Could you [edit] the question to include that? If the results from the DB are correct, we don't really need to care about the SQL, only the format the data is in, and the format you want it to be in.

Comment: No i meant it should be work of backend service rather than SQL or front end... I think it would be bad if UI is directly talking to SQL.

Comment: @SMA Regardless of what "layer" it's in, some part of the code needs to transform the array from one format to the other. The question as I understand it is how to perform that transformation, so moving it from one PHP file to another isn't going to affect the question or answer.

Comment: @IMSoP i understand that. But that's bad practice that you are promoting to.

Comment: @SMA I don't really follow what you think is "promoting bad practice". All we know is there is some data coming from a database, and that data is used to power a graph. Whether that happens in a one-page PHP script for a quick monitoring tool, or in 2 different components of a giant MVC application is completely irrelevant to the question of "how to reformat data from structure A to structure B" (if that is in fact the question, which is unclear).

Comment: Actually, re-reading the question, it seems like maybe PHP is *not* relevant to the question, and nor is the exact structure, because what you're actually struggling with is the *SQL* to get a count of each option. As the suggested answers say, that's a very simple application of SQL "Group By".

Comment: yes GROUP BY was what i was looking for. Sorry for the vague explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid query could be:

```
SELECT option_id, COUNT(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY option_id;
```

Everything else can be handled in application code

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. i think so it is useful

```
SELECT `option_id `,SUM(1) FROM table_name
GROUP BY `option_id `
```